# Am I hired for a job after completing new hire paperwork?

Tags: new-job

I filled out new hire paperwork and was given a company badge.

I also have orientation dates but when I asked about my start date in the department (the orientation is to the company not my specific department) I was told that the manager will determine that.

I called my manager to ask when I would report for my first day, but she hasn't returned my call. I emailed for HR and they again told me it was up to her and forwarded my email to her.  I know she needs me trained asap. So my questions is:  Should I worry that its been three days, and she hasn't returned my call or email yet?

Comment: did they give you a way to fill out and submit timecards?

Comment: Time cards are done eletronically when I walk into the department.  I was given access to the company site to complete direct deposit and instructed to complete benefit choices within 30 days.  I know these are all good signs but it seems strange that they would make all arrangements except for the actual start date in the department.

Comment: Have you signed a contract of employment

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that your employment actually starts when you start your orientation.

Generally most of your other questions will be answered at your orientation.  Depending on the type position you are applying for you may need to pass some certification, or other qualification prior to actually beginning the position.  Many companies with multiple weeks of training are reluctant to tell people that they will be in training for so long prior to their actually beginning the position.

I would expect that you will go from orientation straight into any training that is required, and once that is completed you will begin work in your department.  I would show up at orientation prepared to work and be flexible with your schedule for the next few weeks.  Most training is regular business hours but sometimes during periods of immediate need your training could be accelerated or compressed and off hour attendance may be required.  The only way to find out for sure is probably going to be showing up for your orientation.  But I would not worry about not hearing anything back.

Answer (score 1):

Employment starts from when you get a contract of employment - is this what you meant by new hire paperwork.

Note this could even by a verbal agreement but more normally there should be a document that you sign.